# Issue with building .NET project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, msbuild, entity-framework-migrations

I've got very strange issue with building .NET project. I am using latest Visual Studio 2012.

When I try to build whole solution it says "Build successful". I have several projects in solution and the problem is with one of them. It builds successfully. But the logic is not updating (like some .NET assembly cache)... I cannot debug it as well.

The project contains entity framework code first context and entities, migrations.

I tried:

- Checked solution configuration (I have appropriate checkbox checked)
- Build/Clean/Rebuild
- Visual Studio reboot, reboot with Administrator permissions

What am I missing? Guys, please help. It frustrates me and makes me angry :)

Comment: have you checked to see what the properties are for the .dll for example if it copies local or anything like that..?

Comment: Nothing there. It is absolutely ordinary project. And it worked just fine for several months...

Comment: based on the answer posted I forgot about the obvious.. are you in `Debug mode` or `Release` mode in regards to the project / Solution configuration  perhaps you are looking at the wrong folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing any references between projects and then rebuild any library projects and add the references again.

You say the logic doesn't update, it might be it...

Comment: Hey!!! It helped me! Thank you, Dani! I am not sure, will it get rid of the problem in future...

Comment: Sounds like you might have referenced dll instead of project, another possible couse for similar behavior is that your assembly is loaded from somewhere else - GAC or VS private assemblies or any other autoload location.

Comment: I had this happen when I added a "by project", and then I changed the unique GUID (in the Assembly.cs) to something else.  It continued to compile on the dev box, but started failing on the build machine.  I just had to un-reference the project, and re-add it "by project" (again) for it to get the correct guid.  Then all was good.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the clean does not completely clean everything. When this happens, I manually delete all the contents of the `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` depending on your solution's configuration. If your intention is to extend the clean target, [this](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,670b78b1-4968-46b1-905b-3ae903f3d9cb.aspx) is one of the best sources.

Comment: I've tried to remove bin and obj and after rebuild, all the files were created back. I see my code when I browse the dll's with reflector... How can it be possible? The functionality is not updated..